# Installing Google Apps on Genymotion

Tags: android, flash, genymotion

I would like to open Android apps under Ubuntu.
Tried to follow this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su/20137324#20137324
I created "Custom Tablet 5.1.0" virtual device
I flashed Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip without problem. I shut down and powered on Android machine.
I downloaded gapps from http://opengapps.org/ choosing: Platform ARM, Android 5.1, Variant stock.
Zip successfully transferred to virtual device, but during flashing I came with following message: `Failed to flash file open_gapps-arm-5.1-stock-20160420.zip`
How can I get around this? Where to look for what really happened? I am new to Genymotion.
If you know other, easier, way to open apps from Google Store under Ubuntu please let me know.